# Find the optimal clipped circle

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

Given a `NxN` integer lattice, I want to find the clipped circle which maximizes the sum of its interior lattice point values.

Each lattice point `(i,j)` has a value `V(i,j)` and are stored in the following matrix `V`:

```
      [[ 1,  1, -3,  0,  0,  3, -1,  3, -3,  2],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1,  0, -2,  0,  0,  1, -3],
       [ 2,  2, -3,  2, -2, -1,  2,  2, -2,  0],
       [-2,  0, -3,  3,  0,  2, -1,  1,  3,  3],
       [-1, -2, -1,  2,  3,  3, -3, -3,  2,  0],
       [-3,  3,  2,  0, -3, -2, -1, -3,  0, -3],
       [ 3,  2,  2, -1,  0, -3,  1,  1, -2,  2],
       [-3,  1,  3,  3,  0, -3, -3,  2, -2,  1],
       [ 0, -3,  0,  3,  2, -2,  3, -2,  3,  3],
       [-1,  3, -3, -2,  0, -1, -2, -1, -1,  2]]
```

The goal is to maximize the sum of values `V(i,j)` of the lattice points lying on the boundary and within interior of a (clipped) circle with radius `R`, with the assumptions and conditions:

- the circle has center at (0,0)
- the circle can have any positive radius (not necessarily an integer radius, i.e., rational).
- the circle may be clipped at two lattice points, resulting in a diagonal line as shown in the picture. This diagonal line has a slope of -45 degrees.

Some additional details:

The score for a clipped circle is the sum of all the integers that are both within the circle (or on the border) and on the side of the diagonal line including (0,0).   The values on (or near) the border are -3, 1, 3, -1, -3, 3, -1, 2, 0, 3.

Even though the circle can have any radius, we need only consider circles that intersect a grid point precisely so there are n^2 different relevant radiuses. Further, we need only record one position where the circle intersects with the diagonal line to fully specify the clipped circle. Note that this intersection with the diagonal does not need to be at an integer coordinate.

If the optimal solution doesn't have the diagonal clipping the circle at all then we need only return the radius of the circle.

What I have found so far:

If we only wanted to find the optimal circle we could do that quickly in time proportional to the input size with:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
np.random.seed(40)

def find_max(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    sum_dist = np.zeros(2 * n * n, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            dist = i**2 + j**2
            sum_dist[dist] += A[i, j]
    cusum = np.cumsum(sum_dist)
    # returns optimal radius with its score
    return sqrt(np.argmax(cusum)), np.max(cusum)
A = np.random.randint(-3, 4, (10, 10))
print(find_max(A))
```

How quickly can the optimal clipped circle be found?

Comment: By "how quickly", do you mean what is the optimal time complexity as a function of *n*?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes that is right.

Comment: "In the picture, this would include -2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, -2, 1, -2, 0" -- where are these values? Wouldn't the included values 'on or near the border' be: 3, 1, -2, -2, 0, -3, -3, 0, 3, 0? (going clockwise from the 3 at coordinates 0,7)

Comment: @Dave I had changed the image without changing those numbers. Thank you for spotting that!

Comment: The naive approach is `O(n^5)`. The best I can come up with is `O(n^3)`. I keep thinking that `O(n^2.5)` should be doable, but can't quite figure it out.

Comment: @btilly O(n^2.5) would be amazing!

Comment: Hi. Why did you remove the picture? The picture was great, it made it so much simpler to understand the problem

Comment: @Stef I didn't have permission to post it. You are right a picture would be very helpful.

Comment: @Simd The algorithm for calculating the optimal circle is mathematically incorrect and misleading. It assumes that the values are constant. The calculation of the integral of a variable function in a circle is done with respect to the radius (r) and the angle (theta).

Comment: @SudoKoach I don't understand.  The problem has an input matrix of integers as input.

Comment: Indeed, these are integer values, but these values vary randomly between -3 and +3. Which means you can have several identical maxima. You use the np.cumsum(sum_dist) function to calculate the integral, but it is an integral with respect to dist=r². Except an integral of a variable function in a circle is made with respect to r and theta in polar coordinates. The argmax(cusum) function detects the first "circle" maximum that occurs in the cusum vector.

Comment: If we use this maximum to find the "clipped" maximum by proceeding top/down from the optimum circle, we may miss a "clipped" maximum which is beyond this optimum "circle".
Question: Have you tested this algorithm for various values of N and for various distributions of random values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by creating a cumulative frequency table, or a fenwick tree. You'll have a record for each radius of circle, with value corresponding to explored weights at that distance from the origin. Then, begin a BFS from the origin.

For each diagonal "frontier", you'll need to update your table/tree with the radius:weight key-value pair (add weight to existing value). You'll also need to then query the table/tree for the current cumulative sum at each radius just added, noting the maximum and updating a global running maximum accordingly.

Once your search terminates, you'll have the maximum sum for your clipped-circle. If you want to reconstruct the circle, just store the max radius and BFS depth along with the global max sum itself.

This will give you your solution in `O(N^2 log N)` time, as there will be N^2 updates and queries, which are `O(log N)` each.

The intuition behind this solution is that by exploring along this diagonal "frontier" outward, you implicitly clip all your circles you query since the weights above/right of it haven't been added yet. By calculating the max (at each search depth) for just the radii that were just updated, you also enforce the constraint that the circles intersect the clipping line at an integer coordinate.

**Update**
Here is python code showing this in action. It needs cleaned up, but at least it shows the process. I opted to use cumulative frequency / max arrays, instead of trees, since that'll probably lend itself to vectorization with numpy for OP.

```py
def solve(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)

    max_radius_sqr = 2 * (n - 1) ** 2
    num_bins = max_radius_sqr.bit_length() + 1

    frontier = [(0, 0)]

    csum_arr = [[0] * 2 ** i for i in range(num_bins)[::-1]]
    cmax_arr = [[0] * 2 ** i for i in range(num_bins)[::-1]]

    max_csum = -float("inf")
    max_csum_depth = None
    max_csum_radius_sqr = None

    depth = 0

    while frontier:
        next_frontier = []

        if depth + 1 < n:  # BFS up
            next_frontier.append((0, depth + 1))

        # explore frontier, updating csums and maximums per each
        for x, y in frontier:
            if x + 1 < n:  # BFS right
                next_frontier.append((x + 1, y))

            index = x ** 2 + y ** 2  # index is initially the radius squared

            for i in range(num_bins):
                csum_arr[i][index] += matrix[y][x]  # update csums

                if i != 0:  # skip first, since no children to take max of
                    sum_left  = csum_arr[i-1][index << 1]  # left/right is tree notation of the array
                    max_left  = cmax_arr[i-1][index << 1]
                    max_right = cmax_arr[i-1][index << 1 | 1]
                    cmax_arr[i][index] = max(max_left, sum_left + max_right)  # update csum maximums

                index >>= 1  # shift off last bit, update sums/maxs again, log2 times

        # after entire frontier is explored, query for overall max csum over all radii
        # update running global max and associated values
        if cmax_arr[-1][0] > max_csum:
            max_csum = cmax_arr[-1][0]
            max_csum_depth = depth
            index = 0
            for i in range(num_bins-1)[::-1]:  # reconstruct max radius (this could just as well be stored)
                sum_left  = csum_arr[i][index << 1]
                max_left  = cmax_arr[i][index << 1]
                max_right = cmax_arr[i][index << 1 | 1]

                index <<= 1
                if sum_left + max_right > max_left:
                    index |= 1
            max_csum_radius_sqr = index

        depth += 1
        frontier = next_frontier

    # total max sum, dx + dy of diagonal cut, radius ** 2
    return max_csum, max_csum_depth, max_csum_radius_sqr
```

Calling this with the given test case produces the expected output:

```
    matrix = [
        [-1,  3, -3, -2,  0, -1, -2, -1, -1,  2],
        [ 0, -3,  0,  3,  2, -2,  3, -2,  3,  3],
        [-3,  1,  3,  3,  0, -3, -3,  2, -2,  1],
        [ 3,  2,  2, -1,  0, -3,  1,  1, -2,  2],
        [-3,  3,  2,  0, -3, -2, -1, -3,  0, -3],
        [-1, -2, -1,  2,  3,  3, -3, -3,  2,  0],
        [-2,  0, -3,  3,  0,  2, -1,  1,  3,  3],
        [ 2,  2, -3,  2, -2, -1,  2,  2, -2,  0],
        [-2, -1,  0,  1,  0, -2,  0,  0,  1, -3],
        [ 1,  1, -3,  0,  0,  3, -1,  3, -3,  2],
    ][::-1]
    print(solve(matrix))

# output: 13 9 54
```

In other words, it says the maximum total sum is `13`, with a diagonal cut stagger (dx + dy) of `9`, and radius squared of `54`.

If I have some time tonight or this weekend, I'll clean up the code a bit.

Comment: The circle doesn't need to intersect the diagonal at an integer coordinate. My observation was that it we only need to consider circles that intersect some integer coordinate in the grid.

Comment: Adding a point on the diagonal frontier can change the max prefix sum, but the max prefix sum might not end at that point.  I think you need to augment your Fenwick tree with some additional info so that you can find the max prefix sum over the whole tree in O(log N) time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans re-reading, it don't think I made it clear enough that you should add all points of that BFS depth (along the diagonal), then after that begin your csum query, not after each individual point. If done that way, there's no issue.
For your second point, yes, you will need a `max_csum` attribute for each node, the formula is just `max_csum = max(left.max_csum, left.sum + right.max_csum)`. Forgot to mention that, thanks.

Comment: @simd, in that case, just query for the overall maximum csum of all radii, not just those radii that you updated.  If you use a fenwick tree, you'll need the formula in my above comment, if you use a cumulative frequency table, then augment it with max_csum table with the same formula.

Comment: If I understand correctly, we  first compute `sum_dist` as in the code in the question. But I am not clear what we then do for each diagonal. Would you be able to add some code to explain?

Comment: @Simd sure. I had to quickly cobble this together before work, so it may have an off-by-one edgecase or something, and its not cleaned up at all, but it should demonstrate the process. It gives the correct result (score, radius, diagonal stagger) for your example as well.

Answer (score -1):

The obvious solution is `O(N^2 log N)` - we calculate the distance from `(0, 0)` to each point of the grid, sort them by ascending order, and iterate through the sorted list and track the accumulated sum, saving the largest sum of the numbers (it's like gradually "growing" the circle). The blue diagonal line is just an additional constraint.

However, I have a strong hunch that it can be done in `O(N^2)` without the sorting part (that adds `log N`). There should be some obvious traversal order from `(0,0)` which will allow us to visit the grid points according to their L2 distance to the origin in linear time, without having to sort.

Comment: That doesn't handle the diagonal clipping.

Comment: It does, diagonal clipping is just an additional constraint.

Comment: In this problem we are choosing both the circle radius and the diagonal line. So both have to be optimized together.